# how to setup multiple static IP on WAN in pfSense

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, pfsense, static-ip

I have from my ISP a static address (say 70.10.170.100) as well as a range of 2 hosts 69.169.20.120/30.  I get handed the first static address when I connect via PPPoE.

I have added a virtual IP entry in pfSense | Firewall: proxy ARP with the 69.169.20.120/30 range.
From the outside I can ping one of my hosts in the range, i.e. ping 69.169.20.121 works.

But I cannot figure out how to setup a NAT port forward so that I can reach an internal webserver from the outside over one of the two range host IP addresses? I don't want to use NAT 1:1 because I mostly want to have multiple port 80 to the same web server.

Answer (score 0):

In proxy ARP write the second staticIP/30.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/353297)

Comment: Thomas this is the solution that does not need clarification. Before commenting randomly, try it.

Comment: @AlessandroSecchi OP here, (completely forgot about this question).  I have no idea where to set the proxy ARP.  There's the ARP table in diagnostics, but it doesn't mention proxy, and shouldn't a secondary static IP be a function of the WAN interface?